# Programmatically Move a File to Program Files without Admin Rights?

Tags: c#

I've got a very simple exe that downloads in a zip file with some other stuff. What I want to do is move one of those files to a location in program files. When I do this though, it says I don't have permissions unless I run it as admin. I don't always have this option. I doubt it, but is there anyway to do this without admin rights? This is all it's doing:

```
File.Copy(@"c:/file.txt", @"C:/Program Files (x86)/Folder/file.txt");
```

Comment: It's simply no way except a security hole of OS, after `WinXp`. But older `Windows(TM)` not meet the requirement of `.Net Framework`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that unless you (as an admin) already set up access rights for your user to write to that directory. Normal access rights to Program Files will not let regular users write to that location, and there is no override.

One reason for this is to prevent [viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_form_of_words_ending_in_-us#Virus) from infecting your system. Since `Program Files` is shared by all users, a file placed there may be executed by all users that log on to the system.

Also, it prevents badly written programs from saving settings in Program Files, which may affect/overwrite other users' settings.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;


 var dir = System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%systemdrive%\\Program Files");

        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
            //System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            string fileName = "file.txt";
            string sourcePath = @"C:/"; //@AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string targetPath = dir;


            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

        }
```